# Is there a more idiomatic way of writing this?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

I'm slightly afraid that this question isn't the right form for this, so if there is a better way to phrase/pose this question, let me know.

Basically, I was reading the other day about a coordinate system some guy made. It was cool and I thought about how *I* would make my own better. So I did.

In short, it divides the Mercator map into 36 zones, recursively, where each zone is represented by a number or letter (caps don't matter).

Anyway, I represent this with a class of Javascript object called a Zone. However, the constructor uses some of the object's prototype methods. Not knowing what else to do, I did this (you can ignore the meat of it, I'm mainly querying about the object structure):

```
// Internally, zones are represented from (0,0) to (1,1), as in the positive quadrant
// on the Cartesian plane. Since it is just a square, we only need the bottomLeft
// point and a 'zoomLevel' to determine the side lengths, which is (1/6)**zoomLevel.
var Zone = function () { this.constructor.apply(this,arguments) }
Zone.prototype = {
    constructor: function(address) {
        if (!address) {
            this.x = 0
            this.y = 0
            this.address = ""
            this.zoomLevel = 0
        } else {
            this.address = address.toString(36)
            coords = hexcoords(this.address.slice(0,1))
            this.x = coords[0]
            this.y = coords[1]
            this.zoomLevel = 1
        }
        while (this.zoomLevel < this.address.length) {
            this.descend(this.address.slice(this.zoomLevel, this.zoomLevel+1), true)
        }
    },
    topRight: function () { return [ this.x + Math.pow((1/6),this.zoomLevel),
                                     this.y + Math.pow((1/6),this.zoomLevel) ] },
    toLatLong: function (x,y) {
        // top left corner is -180 longitude and 85.05112878
        if (!x && !y) {
            // latitude and longitude are kind of reversed from x/y
            return [85.05112878 - 170.1022*(1-this.y), -180 + 360 * this.x ]
        }
        return [85.05112878 - 170.1022*(1-y), -180 + 360 * x ]
    },
    clone: function () { return new Zone(this.address) },
    // Descending is basically just always moving the bottomLeft point some nonnegative
    // amount in the positive direction. Luckily, the subzone allows us to calculate
    // that easily.
    descend: function (zone, dontchangeaddress) {
        this.x += Math.pow((1/6),this.zoomLevel)*hexcoords(zone)[0]
        this.y += Math.pow((1/6),this.zoomLevel)*hexcoords(zone)[1]
        if (!dontchangeaddress) {
            this.address = this.address.concat(zone.toString(36))
        }
        this.zoomLevel += 1
        return this
    }
}
```

Basically, my question is asking if there is a better or more idiomatic way to define an Object and it's properties so that they can be used in the constructor?

(Feel free to give other forms of criticism or advice, if desired.)

Comment: Not sure why you did this anyway. What would make the use of `this.constructor` "safer" then `this.descend`?

Comment: As per my response to your answer, I originally thought that it wasn't evaluated yet, but it threw vague errors at me that I couldn't (quickly) debug. I guessed that defining the prototype in this way would either not get evaluated until constructed OR do it in such a way that it defines everything 'at once'. It wasn't very scientific or thoroughly thought out. My initial intuition was correct, I just must have made a mistake somewhere early on.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely write

```
Zone = function(address) {
    if (!address) {
        this.x = 0
        this.y = 0
        this.address = ""
        this.zoomLevel = 0
    } else {
        this.address = address.toString(36)
        coords = hexcoords(this.address.slice(0,1))
        this.x = coords[0]
        this.y = coords[1]
        this.zoomLevel = 1
    }
    while (this.zoomLevel < this.address.length) {
        this.descend(this.address.slice(this.zoomLevel, this.zoomLevel+1), true)
    }
};
```

if you don't actually *invoke* `Zone` before augmenting its prototype.

```
Zone.prototype = ...
new Zone(); // ok
```

Or, more generalized:
In Javascript, any function can reference object properties that don't seem to exist at the time the function is being defined. That is because the references are not resolved until the function actually is invoked, i.e. at runtime.

Comment: Herm. You see, I thought that was the case (and that's how I originally wrote it when I converted it to use prototype methods) but it broke on me. I guess I had some other error I wasn't aware of. :/